# Difference between "pois" and "porque"

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palavras, conjunções

> - Não vou à escola, pois não me sinto bem.
> - Não vou à escola, porque não me sinto bem.

What is the difference between "pois" and "porquê"?

And which is more formal?

Comment: Do you want to know the difference in general or in those two sentences?

Comment: I like to the difference in general

Comment: OK, it's just that neither of those would likely be said. Either "não vou à escola; não me sinto bem" (e.g. in response to "what are you doing in bed?" or "não vou à escola porque não me sinto bem" (without comma, e.g. in response to "why are you not going to school?")

Comment: Both sentences are idiomatic. The commas are out of place, that is true.  I am not going to school **as** I don't feel well versus **because** I don't feel well. Very simple, very clear and there's no doubt at all about that.

Comment: In your sentence the meaning is the same, but "pois" is usually less used than "porque" and it has a little bit of formality feeling.

Answer (score 6):

Semanticamente, quer *porque*, quer *pois*, podem introduzir **causas** (caso em que a oração introduzida por *pois*/*porque* tem de descrever uma situação anterior àquela da da oração principal), ou uma **motivação**/**justificação**.

> - Em Lisboa, **porque** é um meio mais cosmopolita, gerou-se uma maior diversidade e instabilidade. [causa]
> - Preferia jogar com a Inglaterra, **porque** os romenos têm um futebol demasiado parecido com o nosso. [justificação]
> - Na altura das chuvas, tinha na escola uns sapatos e umas roupecas para trocar, **pois** chegava todo molhado... [motivação]
> - A água ferveu, **pois** atingiu os 100°C. [causa]

Isto não significa que *porque* e *pois* sejam usados com a mesma frequência relativa para introduzir cada tipo de orações. *Porque* introduz orações causais mais frequentemente do que *pois* e *pois* orações explicativas mais frequentemente do que *porque*.

Uma outra diferença semântica prende-se com o facto de que *porque*, quando é colocado após a oração principal, tende a introduzir informação que é apresentada como nova, que não é do conhecimento geral (*Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian, pág. 2009). Este não é geralmente o caso com *porque* na posição inicial ou com *pois*.

Em termos de registo, *pois* tende a ser mais usado na escrita. A maioria das ocorrências de *pois* na oralidade correspondem a expressões idiomáticas ou a um valor conclusivo (mais no fim da resposta).

Em relação a *porque*, existe uma relação entre o valor semântico e a sua posição (pág. 2008):

> [Q]uando tem um valor explicativo, a oração [com *porque*] ocupa sempre a posição final e é precedida por uma rutura entoacional, marcada por uma vírgula na escrita (cf. (96a)). Quanto tem valor causal, a oração pode ocorrer em posição inicial ou final, mas quando é final, não é geralmente antecedida de rutura entoacional (cf. (96b) e (96c)):
>
> (96) a. O diretor já chegou, *porque as luzes do gabinete estão acesas*.
>          b. *Porque era domingo*, a loja estava fechada.
>          c. A loja estava fechada *porque era domingo*.

Quando *porque* tem um valor *causal*, comporta-se como uma conjunção subordinativa. A subordinação adverbial tem três propriedades que não são satisfeitas em construções *pois*, independentemente do valor semântico (*idem*, pág. 2009):

1. A possibilidade de ocorrência em posição inicial:

   > *Porque estava bom tempo*, os pescadres ficaram em terra.
   >   **Pois estava bom tempo*, os pescadores ficaram em terra.
2. A possibilidade de haver coordenação:

   > Estou cansado *porque tenho tido muito trabalho e porque o meu filho tem estado doente*.
   >   *Estou cansado, *pois tenho tido muito trabalho e pois o meu filho tem estado doente*.
3. A colocação pré-verbal dos pronomes clíticos em orações finitas (só relevante no português europeu):

   > Estou mais aliviado *porque lhe contei a verdade*.
   >   *Estou mais aliviado, *pois lhe contei a verdade*.

Se *porque* introduzir uma oração explicativa, as propriedades sintáticas são geralmente semelhantes àquelas das orações explicativas introduzidas por *que*, propriedades essas que estão entre as de *porque* causal (que satisfaz 1-3) e as de *pois* (que não satisfaz 1-3). Em particular, o ponto 1 não é satisfeito (não é permitida a posição pré-verbal, como já foi mencionado), a ênclise a próclise são ambas possíveis (ponto 2), e a coordenação é possível mas marginal. A *Gramática do Português* dá estes exemplos com *que* (pág. 2010):

> Acorda, *que o sol já vai alto*!
>   **Que o sol já vai alto*, acorda!
>   Tem cuidado, *que ele te bate/bate-te.*
>   ?Vem-te deitar, *que já é tarde e que temos de nos levantar cedo*!

#### *Pois* conclusivo

Este *pois* é semelhante a outros conectores conclusivos como *assim*, *logo*, *por conseguinte*, *por consequência*, *por isso* e *portanto*, mas tendo a particularidade de só poder ocorrer logo após o verbo (*idem*, pág. 1810):

> Os concorrentes ganharam um carro; estavam, *pois*, muito contentes.

#### Expressões idiomáticas com *pois*

**Pois é** é uma «expressão usada para indicar confirmação ou resignação» ([Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pois)).

> O Ex-OO7 Timothy Dalton vai ser pai pela primeira vez, com a bonita idade de 50 anos (**pois é**, não parece, mas é quantos já tem).

No Brasil, existe ainda a expressão [*pois não*](http://www.aulete.com.br/pois).

Comment: The asker needed an explanation in English and not an entire grammatical exegesis. The difference **in general**; not explained. I explained the difference **in general**.

Comment: @Lambie 1) a diferença entre _pois_ e _porque_ é essencialmente **gramatical** (ambos podem transmitir causa ou justificação), 2) o OP não pediu explicitamente uma resposta em inglês, e responder em português a perguntas em inglês é permitido pelas regras e 3) _in general_ tem vários sentidos, e o meu comentário não usa a expressão no sentido vago de "a maioria dos casos", mas sim no sentido lógico, i.e., quero dizer que a equivalência pode exisitir em casos particulares, mas não pode ser _generalizada_ numa regra.

Answer (score 2):

**Porque** is **because** and **pois** is **as**, as used in your sentence.

> I'm not going to school as [pois] I don't feel well.
>
> I'm not going to school because [porque] I don't feel well.

The Portuguese tend to use *pois* a lot in response to someone else's comments, as a way of agreeing with the person and to mean yes.

> — **Gostas de café, não é?**.
> — **Pois, gosto (sim)**. (Portugal)
>
> — **Gosta de café, não é?**
> — **Pois é, gosto sim**. (Brasil).

In Brazilian Portuguese, the *pois é* is more like "well", "in fact", "yes".

These are just general instances of this, not every single detail about the usage.

Comment: -1 Saying _porque_ is _because_ and  _pois_ is _as_ (or _since_ or _for_) explains little and is generally wrong. For instance, you cannot plug _pois_ here: "But, as we cannot know, in all cases, the character of the books thus noticed, the writers of the notices must be held responsible for what they shall say of their contents, and not we.". The rest of the answer is also, at the very least, misleading. An answer of _pois, gosto_ is an agreement (hell, we're answering _gosto_ to a yes/no question), but _pois_ actually introduces hesitation or a concession (will depend on context).

Comment: It is not wrong. I was giving GENERAL usage, and the usage in the sentences POSTED pois eu sei (as I know) o que as frases estão dizendo (what the sentences are saying) (Portugal: estão a dizer). Credo. I explained two different uses: INSIDE a sentence, and starting one. But, like I said, not EVERY SINGLE USAGE.

Comment: If you say that _a_ is _b_, like you, then _a_ and _b_ better be interchangeable. Here, they're clearly not. So if you want to make an analogy to English, you have at least to say the aspects where the analogy applies.

Comment: I never said they were interchangeable. First you say I say explain little then you say I said they were interchangeable. My god, what bad faith. You have basically written an entire grammatical exegesis but not explained the meaning in English as requested.

Comment: I don't know why you find what I write so difficult to comprehend. I didn't say that you said they were interchangeable. I said "then they better be interchangeable". Read it again. What I said was that by saying _a_ is _b_, you're explaining **nothing**; you're not pointing out the aspects in which the two are related. An explanation would only be unnecessary if the two were interchangeable.

Comment: BTW, you have to prefix your comments with @Artefacto, otherwise I'm not notified (the exception is if you're commenting on a question or answer of mine).

Comment: @Artefacto - Whatever you say. Nothing is good enough for some people. Even though you said: neither of those would likely be said. That is simply not true. The structure: Eu + verbo in the negative + pois [as as] is very, very common. So common it makes me wonder about your Portuguese pois não vejo a questão dessa maneira.

Comment: O que é que o cu tem a ver com as calças? Como é que a minha avaliação da frequência do _pois_ causal/explicativo na oralidade está relacionada com os méritos da tua resposta?

Comment: @Artefacto - Uma das caracteristicas desse uso do pois é que em Portugal se usa o tempo todo. O pois é usado em frases que muitas vezes no Brasil usaria porque. Então dizer que não se usa (OK, it's just that neither of those would likely be said.) é na minha opinião, falso.

Comment: **pois** usa-se em Portugal «o tempo todo» com valor conclusivo. Mas mais uma vez, **nada** a ver com a minha crítica à tua resposta. A não ser que estejas a sugerir que o suporte da afirmação _porque is because and pois is as_ é a frequência de cada uma das palavras…